# Use dictionary keys and associated values as wildcards in snakemake

Tags: dictionary, snakemake

I have a great number of analyses that need to be done in one go, and thus I thought that I can make a dictionary and parse the keys and values as wildcards (every snakemake run needs two wildcards to be used).

My dict will look like this:

```
myDict= {
"Apple": ["fruity","red","green"]
"Banana": ["fruity,"yellow"]
        }
```

Here the first key in the dictionary will be **wildcard1**, here {Apple}, with the first value as **wildcard2**, here {fruity}, and run snakemake with these two until the final rule is has been run.

Then the same key will again be used ({Apple} as **wildcard1**) with the second associated value, here {red}, as **wildcard2**, and run snakemake until the last rule has been run.

Then after the final value belonging to {Apple} has been used as **wildcard2**, switch over to {Banana} as **wildcard1** with its first value, {fruity} as **wildcard2**.
This will go on until all keys and their associated values have been used as wildcards and snakemake will stop. (That is keys as **wildcard1**, and their values as **wildcard2**).

My question is if this is possible, and if so, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I bet there is a way to do it with a single expand, but you can use a more verbose list comprehension.  I'll take the files to be `{wc1}_{wc2}.out` for wildcards 1 and 2.  Then you have

```py
myDict= {
"Apple": ["fruity","red","green"],
"Banana": ["fruity","yellow"]
        }

inputs = [expand('{wc1}_{wc2}.out',
                 wc1=key, wc2=value)
          for key, value in myDict.items()]

# inputs = [['Apple_fruity.out', 'Apple_red.out', 'Apple_green.out'], ['Banana_fruity.out', 'Banana_yellow.out']]

rule all:
    input: inputs
```

Edited to address comment:

To make two lists, `keys` and `values`, you can use

```py
keys = []
values = []
for key, value in myDict.items():
    for v in value:
        keys.append(key)
        values.append(v)

print(keys)  # ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Banana']
print(values)  # ['fruity', 'red', 'green', 'fruity', 'yellow']
```

Comment: That's a good solution and I have tried making it work, but unfortunately I need to have the keys and values outputted as this;

KEY=key         
VALUE=value   
 
So in the first run it will be:
KEY={Apple}
VALUE={fruity}

and so on for the rest of the key, value pairs. Any way to make this work?

Comment: If my edit still doesn't address your comment, please refine your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks it does, but the problem is that now snakemake will try to run with all items in the keys list as wildcard1, with all the items in the values list as wildcard2.
This results in e.g 'Apple' as wildcard1 and 'yellow' as wildcard2 being ran togheter, and this is not possible in my pipeline.

Comment: If you are using expand to make your wildcards, you can override the default combination to [use zip](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#i-don-t-want-expand-to-use-the-product-of-every-wildcard-what-can-i-do)